# ffmpeg add subtitle work fine but not in chrom browser

Tags: ffmpeg

My code is:

```
$video='uploads/video/combined.mp4';$vtt='file/sample.vtt';$rand=rand();

shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i '.$video.' -f srt -i  '.$vtt.' -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s mov_text -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng uploads/video/'.$rand.'.mp4 2>&1');
```

Works perfectly in Safari but my problem is the subtitle in chrome browser is not working.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: 1) Remove `-f srt`. You're telling ffmpeg that your WebVTT input is SRT and not WebVTT. ffmpeg should be able to determine the format automatically without needing `-f`. 2) Are you certain Chrome supports "mov_text" (MPEG-4 Streaming Text format ISO 14496-17)? 3) Show the complete log from your ffmpeg command.

Comment: http://betatesterdomain.com/output.php